# Field shouldn't be populated in HTTP Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I specify in ASP.NET model object that certain field should not be populated when the user makes an Post request? 
The other fields should be populated.

- The solution i came up with it is to override the value, but i'm looking for more "clean" solution.

Comment: Your view model should only contain the properties you need

Comment: Thanks I've decided to use a Mapper instead (DTO -> Domain Object) and do this process when mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using that model for more than just one thing. 
If that is the case, I suggest you create a separate model for POST, one that only includes the fields you want to see.

If you use most of the model properties somewhere else then you can have a base class where you share whatever is common and keep the differences in classes which extend the base one.

The main idea here is to make sure that your models only include the properties you want to see and nothing else.